Let $K,L$ be two field. I must prove that $[L:K]=2 \iff $ exists $\gamma\in L\setminus K$ such that $L=K(\gamma)$
Let $K$ and $L$ be two field such that $K\subseteq L$. I must prove that $$[L:K]=2\iff \text{exists}\; \gamma\in L\setminus K\;\text{such that}\; L=K(\gamma).$$
$(\implies)$ Let be suppose thah $[L:K]=2$, then $L$ is a $K-$ vector space of dimensioin $2$. Let $\{1,\gamma\}$ be a basis of the $K-$ vector space $L$, then for all $x\in L$ exist $r,s\in K$ such that $$x=r+s\gamma.$$ We observe that if $\gamma \in K$, then $x\in K$ and therefore $L=K$ and this implies that $[L:K]=1$ and this is a contraddiction. So, $\gamma\in L\setminus K$. Since $L$ is an extention of $K$ that contains $\gamma$ we have that $K(\gamma)\subseteq L$, then from the tower theorem we have that $$[L:K]=[L:K(\gamma)][K(\gamma):K]\implies 2=[L:K(\gamma)][K(\gamma):K]$$
$(\Leftarrow)$ This implication is false, as pointed out in the comments.
Could you give me some hints?
EDIT
For the implication $(\implies)$ We can proceed as follows. After we note that $\gamma\notin K$ then we have that $[K(\gamma):K]\ge 2$ and therefore for the tower theorem we have that $$2=[L:K(\gamma)][K(\gamma):K].$$ This implies that necessarily $[K(\gamma):K]=2$ and $[L:K(\gamma)]=1$ from which follows that $L=K(\gamma)$. It's correct?

The second direction is not true. Actually, it is as far from being true as possible. Where did you find this problem?

Was about to post what @Mark just said. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

@MarkThe exercise only talked about the first implication. I added the other one out of curiosity. I wondered if the opposite implication was also valid.

@JackJ. Oh, ok. Then it's better to write that in the question, that you ask if the other direction is true or not. There are lots of counterexamples. For example, for any field $F$, the simple extension $F(x)/F$ is of infinite degree. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is of degree $3$.
